# Superpowered audio engine in Unity

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, superpowered

Can anyone explain me how to use Superpowered audio library in Unity engine for Android and iOS projects, please? I've found tons of material but nothing about how to use this in Unity. I looked project example "SuperpoweredSpatializer/SuperpoweredUnity" but there use standart Unity audio system. If I need build library, place it somewhere, why I can't find any information in docs how to do that?
Sorry, I'm junior Unity developer and I spent a week trying to understand how it works. Please, help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode folder has a project on how to build a Unity Native Audio Plugin with Superpowered.
The result can be drag-and-dropped into your Unity project, just like how the SuperpoweredUnity example project has the SuperpoweredSpatializer plugin inside.

Comment: I see. It seems that I need two versions of plugins for Anroid and iOS as well. But which difference between this modified plugin by Superpowered and original Unity Native Audio Plugin? Only some superpowered effects? Or low latency feature as well? Does this modified plugin have all functionality like original? I mean using mixer and unity sound effects.

Comment: Unity Native Audio Plugin is a wrapper, where you can put any processing inside, such as Superpowered stuff. In other words, Superpowered goes _inside_ a Unity Native Audio Plugin.

Comment: I still don't understand. I just need to play sound without latency in my mobile project and still have oppotunity for using unity effects and mixer. How can I do this? I don't see any code in "SuperpoweredSDK\SuperpoweredSpatializer\src" for playing sound without latency. Only effects.
Thanks for your responsiveness! :)

Comment: Use the SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer in the plugin.